# preg_replace with multiple expression

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a social networking plugin and in mention name section i develop script like

```
@[mention name](contact: mentio0n user id)
```

but at the time of display i need to reconvert it to **Mention_Name** and for that i have develop a regular expression

```
/@+,*[A-za-z0-9_.' @ # ]+,*[(],*[a-zA-Z:]+,*[0-9]+[)]/

preg_replace("/@+,*[a-zA-z0-9.' ]+,*[(],*[contact:]+,*[0-9]+[)]/", 
            "<a style='color:blue;background-color:#FFFF01;' href=\"\.*/@+,*[A-za-z0-9_.' @ # ]+.*/\">\\0</a>",
            '@[user2](contact:402551501) hello @[user3](contact:402551501)');
```

new how to i convert it to name with Like

```
<a href="id">Name</a>
```

and user can mention more then one person at a post

Comment: What you ask is not clear at all. I suggest you to add several example strings and what you want to obtain for each strings.

Comment: i have data in form 
@[mention name](contact: mentio0n user id) text @[mention name](contact: mentio0n user id) text @[mention name](contact: mention user id)
 and to check following pattern i had write following expression
/@+,*[A-za-z0-9_.' @ # ]+,*[(],*[a-zA-Z:]+,*[0-9]+[)]/
and and through that i want to make 

<a href='url/mentio0n user id'>mention name</a>


and after all output will be Name text name text

and name is mention like on facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think that this is what you are looking for:

```
$text = preg_replace('/@\[([^]]+)]\(contact:([0-9]+)\)/',
                     '<a href="url/$2">$1</a>', $text);
```

Pattern details:

```
@
\[          # a literal [ (must be escaped, since it is a special character)
(           # open capture group 1: name
    [^]]+   # character that isn't a ], one or more times 
)           # close capture group 1
]           # a literal ] (no need to escape)
\(          # a literal ( (must be escaped)
contact: 
(           # open capture group 2: id
    [0-9]+  # one or more digits
)           # close capture group2
\)          # a literal ) (must be escaped)
```

About the replacement string:

A replacement string isn't a regular expression, you can't use regex symbols inside. The only difference with a string is that you can use placeholders that refer to the capture groups of the pattern *( `$1` and `$2` here )*

Comment: its not all there is hashtag implementation also in same expression

@mention simpleText #hashtag all can be in a string